# ZHow to use Zclip in Asp.net MVC razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We are developing site based on ASP.net MVC razor engine. We create serialkey dynamically using guid. we want to allow our users to copy the serial key(which is a label) to clipboard. i have tried using zclip, 
it says

```
$('a#copy-dynamic').zclip({
    path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy:function(){return $('input#dynamic').val();}
});
```

Since I'm new to this MVC, I couldn't find out what is the ID of that label where it is just mentioned as @item.serialkey.  Could someone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@item.serialkey` again inside the JavaScript.

I'm not sure if this is what you were getting at with the `#dynamic`, but if it was meant as a place-holder for the value stored in the model, then the following should do the job.

```
$('a#copy-@item.serialkey').zclip({
    path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy:function(){return $('input#@item.serialkey').val();}
});
```

Comment: It  returns only "item.serialkey" as the copied text, but not the actual guid value.  I have tried different combinations and still I couldnot figure it out. I ve seen sites which uses copy to clipboard functionality only for the text  in textbox/textareas. First of all, is it possible to copy a dynamically changing label to clipboard using zclip?